# How to prepare 'hashed' text data for classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

```
sequence = 'I am Bob'
```

The sequence has been altered in some way, like e.g. letters have been replaced with the subsequent letter (a->b), and spaces with 'ss':

```
hashed_seq = 'JssbnssCpc' #for lack of a better word I'm using 'hashed'
```

In my experience, for text classification, you tokenize the sentence/words with some dictionary, e.g.:

```
vocab = {'<PAD>': 0, 'I': 1, 'Bob': 2, 'am': 3}
tokenized_seq = [1,3,2]
```

How would I prepare (tokenize etc) the data for text classification in my case without decoding them? I only have the data after the algorithm has altered them.

Language: Python

Comment: Can you not just run your "hash" algorithm on the dictionary to get a new dictionary?

Comment: I don't have the exact 'hash' algorithm. All I know is one has been applied on the data I have been provided.

Comment: Substitution ciphers are easy to crack, though. So if you have "enough" text, just reverse engineer the cipher and then translate your dictionary.  Here's the results of a quick google search on cracking substitution ciphers: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/possible-ways-to-crack-simple-hand-ciphers

Comment: Besides this, I dunno what you could do.  The very first task in NLP is usually to "tokenize" the text.  If you don't even know the token separators then what can you do?

Comment: Also, if your "hash" is, in fact, just a substitution cipher, you should edit your question to reflect that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher

Comment: "space" will probably be the most common occurring character sequence, though. So simple frequency analysis will uncover that.

Comment: The problem is that I do not the exact length that space has been substituted with. I wouldn't know what most frequent pattern to look for.

Comment: This also increasingly looks like a cryptography task and my intended task is to solve it as an NLP or ML problem. I might try to split the senteces into single characters, or section with random equal character numbers and see if it works, but my takeaway is that it is not possible to build a classifier with data in this ciphered form using NLP techniques. It shouldn't go into the area of cryptography. Thanks so far.